# Can repeatedly mining & smelting stone be efficient for gaining xp?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Since 12w22, [smelting yields experience orbs](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Smelting#Processing_ores_and_materials).

Stone, when mined with a normal pickaxe (without silk touch enchantment), yields cobblestone.

Smelting cobblestone yields stone and some experience orbs (according to the wiki it's 0.1 xp).

So if one keep smelting cobblestone to stone, then mine the stone to get cobblestone, then keep this going, could it be an efficient way for gaining experience orbs?

---

Don't ask me to try before seeing definite answers <s>because I afraid it would take a lot of time.</s>

**EDIT:**

I don't want anybody to try to waste their own time and give me an empirical answer. I expect seeing some sort of calculation which probably involves probability, and also taking account of something that I may have missed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can indeed get experience orbs by smelting common materials, but you have to use coal or charcoal to do the smelting.

Coal is a limited resource and charcoal requires farming, so this isn't quite a game-breaking XP generation loop.

Comment: having said that, you usually end up with excess cobblestone, so getting in to the habit of smelting cobblestone to stone can net you a significant exp boost

Comment: Using a lava bucket could smelt up to 100 blocks, and as lava isn't hard to find (I can get from the Nether, and in the overworld there are lava pools underground and some even on the surface).

Comment: The furnace eats the bucket too, so make sure you have some spare iron

Comment: @JeffreyLin don't remember since which version, it returns the bucket.

Comment: Bucket is now returned. Use lava, people.

Answer (score 0):

You literally just use the lava from the nether: 1 lava=100 smelt.
And use a bunch of stone picks. Might as well with all the cobble you just mined up.

Comment: This is helpful information but it doesn't really answer the question. Can you add more info about how efficient this is?

Answer (score -1):

Umm using like 7 auto bamboo or sugarcane farm will give the fuel
And stripmine for dimonds will eventually give 4 to 5 stack cobble each day so its super effective

Comment: Hi Shraman, can you specify on the bamboo farm? You can add videos in order to save the person who asked this question's time.

Answer (score -5):

It would give you Much XP, But would damage your pick.
I would not recomend this

Comment: If you have a lot of cobblestone and charcoal, picks are pretty much free.